# Custom UITabBarController in didFinishLaunchingWithOptions selecting tabs throws error

Tags: swift, uitabbarcontroller, appdelegate

I have a custom TabBarController with a function called `openTab`:

```
func openTab(index: Int) {

    let items = tabBar.items as! [RAMAnimatedTabBarItem]

    let currentIndex = self.selectedIndex
    let viewController = viewControllers![currentIndex]

    if let shouldSelect = delegate?.tabBarController?(self, shouldSelectViewController: viewController)
        where !shouldSelect {
            return
    }


    if index != currentIndex {
        self.selectedIndex = index
        let animationItem: RAMAnimatedTabBarItem = items[index]
        let icon = iconsView[index].icon
        let textLabel = iconsView[index].textLabel
        animationItem.playAnimation(icon, textLabel: textLabel)

        let deselelectIcon = iconsView[currentIndex].icon
        let deselelectTextLabel = iconsView[currentIndex].textLabel
        let deselectItem = items[currentIndex]
        deselectItem.deselectAnimation(deselelectIcon, textLabel: deselelectTextLabel)
    }

}
```

In AppDelegate.swift I got:

```
let tabBarController = self.window?.rootViewController as! RAMAnimatedTabBarController
print("tabBarController: \(tabBarController)") // throws no error
tabBarController2.openTab(1) // throws error, see below

*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSRangeException', reason: '*** -[__NSArrayI objectAtIndex:]: index 2147483647 beyond bounds [0 .. 2]'
*** First throw call stack:
(0x26460137 0x348eac77 0x26372217 0x36ecb4 0x36d9d4 0x383d30 0x22954 0x37f8c 0x38190 0x29b2be75 0x29d2242b 0x29d24acf 0x29d2f7a9 0x29d23287 0x2cf32ec1 0x26426255 0x26425519 0x26424073 0x2636f9a1 0x2636f7b3 0x29b25a57 0x29b20635 0x38cec 0x34eb8aaf)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
```

This works though:

```
    let tabBarController = self.window?.rootViewController as! UITabBarController
    tabBarController.selectedIndex = 1
```

But I need the color changes performed in `openTab`, so this is no option.

Comment: The error lays in the line `let currentIndex = self.selectedIndex`. `selectedIndex` will hold the default value of 0 after the view appeared.

Comment: Include updates to your question by editing your question, not adding comments.

Comment: The error indicates three tabs [0 ... 2], yet the index referred is an unusual number 2147483647. Seems like error in allocation of index reference?